# How to access Kubernetes UI via browser?

Tags: ssl, https, kubernetes

I have installed Kubernetes using [contrib/ansible](https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib) scripts.
When I run cluster-info:

```
[osboxes@kube-master-def ~]$ kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes master is running at http://localhost:8080
Elasticsearch is running at http://localhost:8080/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/elasticsearch-logging
Heapster is running at http://localhost:8080/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/heapster
Kibana is running at http://localhost:8080/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/kibana-logging
KubeDNS is running at http://localhost:8080/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns
kubedash is running at http://localhost:8080/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/kubedash
Grafana is running at http://localhost:8080/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/monitoring-grafana
InfluxDB is running at http://localhost:8080/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/monitoring-influxdb
```

The cluster is exposed on localhost with insecure port, and exposed on secure port 443 via ssl

`kube      18103      1  0 12:20 ?        00:02:57 /usr/bin/kube-controller-manager --logtostderr=true --v=0 --master=https://10.57.50.161:443 --   kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/controller-manager.kubeconfig --service-account-private-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/certs/server.key --root-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/certs/ca.crt
kube      18217      1  0 12:20 ?        00:00:15 /usr/bin/kube-scheduler --logtostderr=true --v=0 --master=https://10.57.50.161:443 --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/scheduler.kubeconfig
root      27094      1  0 12:21 ?        00:00:00 /bin/bash /usr/libexec/kubernetes/kube-addons.sh
kube      27300      1  1 12:21 ?        00:05:36 /usr/bin/kube-apiserver --logtostderr=true --v=0 --etcd-servers=http://10.57.50.161:2379 --insecure-bind-address=127.0.0.1 --secure-port=443 --allow-privileged=true --service-cluster-ip-range=10.254.0.0/16 --admission-control=NamespaceLifecycle,NamespaceExists,LimitRanger,SecurityContextDeny,ServiceAccount,ResourceQuota --tls-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/certs/server.crt --tls-private-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/certs/server.key --client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/certs/ca.crt --token-auth-file=/etc/kubernetes/tokens/known_tokens.csv --service-account-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/certs/server.crt`

I have copied the certificates from kube-master machine to my local machine, I have installed the ca root certificate. The chrome/safari browsers are accepting the ca root certificate.
When I'm trying to access the https://10.57.50.161/ui
I'm getting the 'Unauthorized'

How can I access the kubernetes ui?

Answer (score 27):

You can use kubectl proxy.

Depending if you are using a config file, via command-line run

```
kubectl proxy
```

or

```
kubectl --kubeconfig=kubeconfig proxy
```

You should get a similar response

> Starting to serve on 127.0.0.1:8001

Now open your browser and navigate to

<s>http://127.0.0.1:8001/ui/</s> (deprecated, see [kubernetes/dashboard](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard#getting-started))
http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/

You need to make sure the ports match up.

Comment: @pkyeck Thanks for updating the URL. Do you know the reason why they changed it from something very easy to remember?

Comment: no, not really. maybe that was part of making it more secure ...!? ;) or more of a byproduct.

Comment: This is a terrible answer! First of all, it doesn't apply to a remote master node in production. Second, it exposes your master node HTTP!

Answer (score 18):

This works for me that you can access from network

```
kubectl proxy --address 0.0.0.0 --accept-hosts '.*'
```

Comment: Now I can open the Sign-in Page, but I can't sign-in with token.

Comment: Try to use this token which belongs to `clusterrole-aggregation-controller` >

```
kubectl -n kube-system describe secrets `kubectl -n kube-system get secrets | \
  awk '/clusterrole-aggregation-controller/ {print $1}'` | awk '/token:/ {print $2}' 
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
The problem by me was, that I didn't add the certificate.

Answer (score 7):

Quick-n-dirty (and unsecure) way to access the Dashboard:

```
$ kubectl edit svc/kubernetes-dashboard --namespace=kube-system
```

This will load the Dashboard config (yaml) into an editor where you can edit it.

Change line `type: ClusterIP` to `type: NodePort`.

Get the tcp port:

```
$ kubectl get svc kubernetes-dashboard -o json --namespace=kube-system
```

The line with the tcp port will look like:

```
            "nodePort": 31567
```

In newer releases of kubernetes you can get the nodeport from `get svc`:

```
# This is kubernetes 1.7:
donn@host37:~$ sudo kubectl get svc --namespace=kube-system
NAME                   CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
kubernetes-dashboard   10.3.0.234   <nodes>       80:31567/TCP   2h
```

Do `kubectl describe nodes` to get a node IP address.

Browse to:
http://NODE_IP:31567

Good for testing. Not good for production due to lack of security.

Comment: and how to change this back from NodePort to ClusterIP ?

Comment: What is a secure way to do this for production?

Answer (score 6):

Looking at your apiserver configuration, you will need to either present a bearer token (valid tokens will be listed in `/etc/kubernetes/tokens/known_tokens.csv`) or client certificate (signed by the CA cert in `/etc/kubernetes/certs/ca.crt`) to prove to the apiserver that you should be allowed to access the cluster.

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/7307#issuecomment-96130676 describes how I was able to configure client certificates for a GKE cluster on my Mac.

To pass bearer tokens, you need to pass an HTTP header Authorization with a value `Bearer ${KUBE_BEARER_TOKEN}`. You can see an example of how this is done with curl [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/gce/util.sh#L817-L829); in a browser, you will need to install an add-on/plugin to pass custom headers.

Comment: This is not a user-friendly experience for someone who just wants to see the UI in a browser.

Comment: I totally agree (the issue I linked to was opened for that reason). Another way to access the UI is to expose it as an external service and connect to it directly. Unfortunately it doesn't offer any authn/z nor https so this isn't secure.

Comment: This sounds promising -- how does one expose the UI as an external service?

Comment: Run `kubectl get rc --namespace kube-system` to get the name of the replication controller for the dashboard (it should be something like kubernetes-dashboard-v1.0.0). Then run `kubectl expose rc kubernetes-dashboard-v1.0.0` to make it an external service. Note that this will allow anyone who discovers the IP of the dashboard unauthenticated access to it, and the dashboard can mutate your cluster state, meaning that they could pretty easily take over your cluster if they wanted to.

Answer (score 1):

1. kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v1.10.1/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml
2. kubectl proxy &
3. Run the following command in your local laptop(or where you want to access the GUI)

   ## ssh -L 8877:127.0.0.1:8001 -N -f -l root master_IPADDRESS
4. Get the secret key
   kubectl -n kube-system describe secret $(kubectl -n kube-system get secret | awk '/^deployment-controller-token-/{print $1}') | awk '$1=="token:"{print $2}'
5. Open the dashboard
   http://localhost:8877/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/

Perform role-binding if you get any errors.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `kubectl proxy --address=clusterIP --port 8001 --accept-hosts '.*'`

Comment: Is this the cluserIP or the master node IP?

Answer (score -1):

api server is already accessible on 6443 port on the node, but not authorize accesss to https://:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/

i've generated client certificats signed by kubernetes ca cert, and converted to pkcs12 and integreted to my browser... when try to access to the this url they says that user are not authorized to access to the uri...